# kubernetes cadvisor endpoint is not scraped by prometheus

Tags: prometheus, minikube, cadvisor

I have a minikube kubernetes cluster installed, which is monitored via prometheus. The kubernetes version is  v1.13.4 and runs directly on a vm host(--vm-driver=none). I have added a specific job at Prometheus configuration file so as to scrape cadvisor container metrics. The problem is that Prometheus can not scrape the metrics from the cadvisor endpoint.

I included the following configuration at my prometheus.yml

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node
  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement:  kubernetes.default.svc:443
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
```

But at the prometheus targets web UI (http://my_ip:30900/targets) i see the "kubernetes-cadvisor" at DOWN state with the following Error message

```
http://kubernetes.default.svc:443/api/v1/nodes/minikube/proxy/metrics/cadvisor: context deadline exceeded
```

[image: Prometheus targets]

kubernetes.default.svc:443 is supposed to be the default cluster DNS, accesible from within a pod but as expected i can not ping it within the prometheus pod.

Fortunately i noticed that i can fetch succesfully all cadvisor container metrics from url:

```
http://my_dashboard_ip_and_port/api/v1/nodes/minikube/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
```

the logs within the prometheus pod are:

```
kubectl logs prometheus-deployment-6f64ff68f9-8c9xm
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.939973334Z caller=main.go:285 msg="no time or size retention was set so using the default time retention" duration=15d
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.940326462Z caller=main.go:321 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.8.1, branch=HEAD, revision=4d60eb36dcbed725fcac5b27018574118f12fffb)"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.94039376Z caller=main.go:322 build_context="(go=go1.11.6, user=root@bfdd6a22a683, date=20190328-18:04:08)"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.940455316Z caller=main.go:323 host_details="(Linux 4.15.0 #1 SMP Tue Mar 26 02:53:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 prometheus-deployment-6f64ff68f9-8c9xm (none))"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.94050961Z caller=main.go:324 fd_limits="(soft=1048576, hard=1048576)"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.940570849Z caller=main.go:325 vm_limits="(soft=unlimited, hard=unlimited)"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.941555805Z caller=main.go:640 msg="Starting TSDB ..."
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.941946171Z caller=web.go:418 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.946861683Z caller=main.go:655 msg="TSDB started"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.947193152Z caller=main.go:724 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.948922627Z caller=kubernetes.go:191 component="discovery manager scrape" discovery=k8s msg="Using pod service account via in-cluster config"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.950164896Z caller=kubernetes.go:191 component="discovery manager scrape" discovery=k8s msg="Using pod service account via in-cluster config"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.951281382Z caller=kubernetes.go:191 component="discovery manager scrape" discovery=k8s msg="Using pod service account via in-cluster config"
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.952276845Z caller=main.go:751 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
level=info ts=2019-03-29T14:33:18.952303937Z caller=main.go:609 msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
```

but i do not know how to configure correctly the Prometheus yml file so as to  be able to fetch the exposed metrics also via the Prometheus.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you may have to use HTTPS schema for scraping request against HTTP, that seems to remain in your configuration:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'

  scheme: https

  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
  bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node

  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
```

In order to skip API server certificate verification you can add `insecure_skip_verify: true` parameter to the existing `tls_config`:

```
tls_config:
  ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
  insecure_skip_verify: true
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I upgraded the kubernetes version to v1.14.0 so as to have a more stable environment and i also deployed minikube upon virtualbox version 5 so as to avoid all (--vm-driver=none) secondary effects. Upon the configuration you proposed my i get the response ```server returned HTTP status 403 Forbidden``` message with the following https endpoint (https://kubernetes.default.svc:443/api/v1/nodes/minikube/proxy/metrics/cadvisor). Any extra recommendations?

Comment: Have you applied `ClusterRole` and  `ClusterRoleBinding` for Prometheus service account, like described [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/rbac-setup.yml)?

Comment: mine was slightly different. i also tried the recommenced rbac example and goτ the same error message :-(

Comment: Can you share logs from prometheus pod in order to evaluate the reason for `403` issue?

Comment: just updated my question with prometheus pod logs. i do not see any strange log messages

Comment: Also  i tryied to access the kubernetes cluster within the prometheus pod and got this: ```/prometheus $ wget https://kubernetes.default.svc:443/api/v1/nodes/minikube/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
Connecting to kubernetes.default.svc:443 (10.96.0.1:443)
wget: note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```  Should i do something extra about the certificate validation as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/#trusting-tls-in-a-cluster)?

Comment: Let's try to make a request using Bearer token authorization from minikube host: fetch Token and ensure that service account name is `prometheus`: `MY_TOKEN="$(kubectl get secret $(kubectl get sa prometheus -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}') ) -o jsonpath='{$.data.token}' | base64 -d)"` and then make a request: `curl -v -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $MY_TOKEN" https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/nodes/minikube/proxy/metrics/cadvisor`.

Comment: Might be mistake in parentheses brackets, correction: `MY_TOKEN="$(kubectl get secret $(kubectl get sa prometheus -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')  -o jsonpath='{$.data.token}' | base64 -d)"`

Comment: i got the same error ```note: TLS certificate validation not implemented
server returned error: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden``` i also compared the token i fetched from kubectl  command with the one that is included into the prometheus pod here  ```/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token ```.they are the same. Seems to be an authorization issue...but why?

Comment: Maybe RBAC authorization is not enabled within minikube, check this GitHub [thread](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/1368).